# Pegar id de tabela mysql em aplicação

Tags: java, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java onde preciso resgatar o id de uma tabela Curso (idCurso, nomeCurso, tipoCurso). Estou tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
public class Teste4 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        Connection con = new ConnectionFactory().getConnection();
        int id = 0;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        String query = "SELECT idCurso FROM Curso WHERE nomeCurso = "
                + "' xiu ' AND tipoCurso = "
                + "' Técnico '";
        try{
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                id = rs.getInt("idCurso");
            }
        }catch (SQLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Teste4() {


        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(157, 157, 157))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(139, 139, 139)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(138, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JFNovoCurso janela = new JFNovoCurso();
        System.out.println(getId());
        janela.setId(getId());
        janela.setVisible(true);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste4.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste4.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste4.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teste4.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Teste4().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

O resultado dessa consulta é 0, e quando faço a mesma consulta no mysql ele retorna algum valor para o id, então acho que não é sintaxe.

Classe ConnectionFactory:

```
public class ConnectionFactory {

    Connection con;

    public Connection getConnection(){

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tcc";
        try {
            return (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "GUstavo08!");
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("Problemas na conexão " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja que tem espaços nos seus paramêtros e como está usando o `=` nao vai funcionar.

Modifique a linha para ficar exatamente como abaixo:

```
String query = "SELECT idCurso FROM Curso WHERE nomeCurso = 'xiu' AND tipoCurso = 'Técnico'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o problema esteja no espaço entre as aspas `' Xiu '` e `' Técnico '`. Quando ele executa o PreparedStatement, por conciderar esses espaços, acaba não encontrando nenhuma tupla que corresponda retornando um ResultSet vazio. Além disto proponho as seguintes mudanças no teu código:

1. Utilizar os método de `setString()` do objeto PreparedStatement
2. Como neste caso apenas uma tupla deve ser retornada então ao invés de um `while (rs.next())` utilize `if(rs.next()`
3. O parâmetro id do método `setId(int id)` acaba não sendo utilizado mas força você a toda invocação deste método definir uma variável que não servirá para nada, seria melhor se o método não recebesse parâmetros e você definisse uma variável local.

O código ficaria assim:

```
public void setId() {
    int aux = 0;
    String query = "SELECT idCurso FROM Curso WHERE nomeCurso = ? AND tipoCurso = ?;";
    try{
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setString(1, "Xiu");
        stmt.setString(2, "Técnico");

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) aux = rs.getInt("idCurso");

    }catch (SQLException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.id = aux;
}
```